# Integrating Gigya's login to My application login(using shiro apache)

Tags: java, shiro, gigya

My application login is developed using Shiro Apache, it's working fine but now i want to integrate that application Gigya's login Any one please specify the steps to add i follow the official website for that mentioned below i didn't got that

http://developers.gigya.com/030_Server_SDKs/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found solution for my Question
First open the below link 
https://platform.gigya.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSite%2fpartners%2fDashboard.aspx 
click on Request an Account, then register get API key and secretkey

download GSJavaSDK.jar file from http://developers.gigya.com/030_Server_SDKs/java site and place in lib folder then add the below code in login page(html or xhtml)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript" 
       src="http://cdn.gigya.com/JS/socialize.js?apikey=2_Y82PzwJ_chSFImHXaIDJClnLyJzmk-VFOavSsaNTzl6m901s_NNxRAS0xJ3bd3_N">
    </script>   
</head>
<body >
<br />
    <p>Please sign in using one of the following providers:</p>
    <div id="loginDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        gigya.socialize.showLoginUI({containerID: "loginDiv", cid:'', width:220, height:60,
                redirectURL: "http://wikifiles.gigya.com/Socialize/PostLoginPage.htm",
                showTermsLink:false, hideGigyaLink:true // remove 'Terms' and 'Gigya' links
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

then deploy the application and Run